# How to make sure a POST is requested from specific domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any property in [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) that can make sure if the request is a `POST` request and it is coming from specific domain?

```
private bool IsRequestedFromDomain(string domain)
{
  // Request.Form is from domain ?
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

Note this header can be faked.

For a list of server variables, please take a look: [ASP ServerVariables Collection](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp)

Comment: can be modified even when redirected from https to https? I mean if HTTPS is on?

Comment: yes, it can; note it is your user browser which make that request, so it can place (or fake) any HTTP header.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Referer, but it can be modified.

Only way how to be sure is to send some , randomly generated value to form, store it to session, and in IsRequestedFromDomain compare it.

Comment: can be modified even when redirected from https to https? I mean if HTTPS is on?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`Request.UrlReferrer`, though it isn't reliable as it can be easily faked and may be changed by proxies.

Comment: can be modified even when redirected from https to https? I mean if HTTPS is on?